# Time driven event in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

Am trying to implement a function in Codeigniter that is called after end of each month so that it can remind users to pay a fee. How can i implement this in Codeigniter. Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried so far to achieve this ?

Comment: u can use ajax call in every weeks...`setintervel`

Comment: I was for the idea of inserting a date in the database then checking it each time an user loads a page but that not a good idea because it's manual and so one can forget to insert the date in the database

Comment: When using ajax setinterval how will i handle the months since some may have different days?

Comment: better way is to use set a cron job. just make a controller and a function within it, hence you can create a url to this. and set this url in cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create crontab job and call Your method at the end of each month (You can set it at crontab). You can access CodeIgniter methods via

`php5 index.php yourcontroller yourmethod`

Also be sure to check if request came from CLI in Your method:

```
<?php

class Yourcontroller extends CI_Controller {

     function index(){

     }

  function yourmethod(){
    if(!$this->input->is_cli_request())
       die('CLI only');
    // add Your code below like this:
    $this->load->model('remindermodel');
    $this->remindermodel->remindToPay();
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: in my script.bat should i edit it like this ? "C:\xampp\php" -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\Test1.1\application\controllers\CronController\myMethod"

Comment: @user3278647 nope, something like `"C:\xampp\php" -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\Test1.1\index.php" CronController myMethod `. You need to execute index.php and send params to it. And check path to php, I think in Windows it must contain `php.exe` (`C:\xampp\php\php.exe`)